# Why my Swift code explodes when comparing upper to lower case?

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud

I'm actually learning swift and I'm testing the switch control flow. I try this code on [IBM Swift Sandbox](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/):

```
let const = "Z"

switch const {

case "a" ,
     "A": print("La primera letra del abecedario")
case "z": print("La ultima letra del abecedario")
default:  print("NPI de que letra se trate")

}
```

It all works fine, tested with `const` = {"a","A","f","z"}. But when `const` is "Z" i get this [error](http://pastebin.com/4TaacAYs):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
0  swift-build-tool 0x000000000050bade llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 46
1  swift-build-tool 0x000000000050ca49
2  swift-build-tool 0x000000000050cd53
3  libpthread.so.0  0x00007f960ca22330
4  libc.so.6        0x00007f960bc5fc37 gsignal + 55
5  libc.so.6        0x00007f960bc63028 abort + 328
6  libstdc++.so.6   0x00007f960c56a535 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 341
7  libstdc++.so.6   0x00007f960c5686d6
8  libstdc++.so.6   0x00007f960c568703
9  libstdc++.so.6   0x00007f960c568922
10 libstdc++.so.6   0x00007f960c5ba800 std::__throw_system_error(int) + 128
11 libstdc++.so.6   0x00007f960c5bbd68 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) + 584
12 swift-build-tool 0x0000000000494d6d
13 swift-build-tool 0x0000000000494b0d
14 swift-build-tool 0x0000000000494a01 llbuild::buildsystem::createLaneBasedExecutionQueue(llbuild::buildsystem::BuildExecutionQueueDelegate&, int) + 49
15 swift-build-tool 0x0000000000490ba8 llbuild::buildsystem::BuildSystemFrontendDelegate::createExecutionQueue() + 264
16 swift-build-tool 0x00000000004b98e9
17 swift-build-tool 0x00000000004b9823 llbuild::buildsystem::BuildSystem::build(llvm::StringRef) + 67
18 swift-build-tool 0x000000000049150d llbuild::buildsystem::BuildSystemFrontend::build(llvm::StringRef) + 1405
19 swift-build-tool 0x000000000048e086
20 swift-build-tool 0x000000000048dc7a main + 170
21 libc.so.6        0x00007f960bc4af45 __libc_start_main + 245
22 swift-build-tool 0x000000000048db04
swift-build: error: Child process exited with signal
```

Comment: This is a compiler bug. Report it and move on. Not reproducible on Xcode 8.2 for me.

Comment: I just tested this code in Playground in XCode Version 8.2 (8C38).  All works as expected with `const == "Z"`.  Clean build, discard derived data, upgrade XCode?

Comment: Im actually using bluemix because dont have a mac right now.

Comment: Oh.  Then that's most likely an issue on IBM side.  Probably they are pulling the carpet from under your snippet too soon, or some other issue.  For example, I am getting timeouts from them right now.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test at home XCode and see if it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Trying your code in the Sandbox now, it looks like it works just fine with `const = "Z"`. This was an error on the Sandbox end, it looks like. We were having issues with a handful of our servers over the holidays, and we're working on getting them fixed. Your code seems to be correct.